# Manual closing inside try-with-resource

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Let's say I'm using a poorly documented third party library, one for which no source code is available. One of the library's methods accepts an `InputStream` to load various data.

Due to the lack of documentation, it's not clear whether or not the method closes the stream once it's done with it, so one possible solution might be to wrap the call in a try-with-resource, just to be on the safe side.

Unfortunately, the Java specification makes (as far as I can tell) no mention of what happens if a resource is manually closed inside a try-with-resource. Does anyone happen to know?

Comment: You can just try it out, don't you?

Comment: @Fildor It's generally a bad practice to just "try and guess" instead of looking at the documentation (even if there, doc is poor). Just because a function returns `1` for `-1` and `1` doesn't make it the `abs` function.

Comment: @Xenos I didn't mean "try and guess". I meant black-box-testing. If documentation is poor, you want to know as much as possible about that function. So you will shoot a sophisticated testset at it (at least I would). Then I'd code something that is stable even if the suspicious function behaves funny. And I never said "instead of looking into the docs". BTW: I *had* encounters where the docs were *plain wrong*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will entirely depend on the implementation of the resource itself. The try-with-resource statement is "just" syntactic sugar (but oh so sweet) for calling `close()` within a `finally` block (and preserving exceptions etc).

So long as the stream supports `close()` being called twice - which I expect most implementations do, and the contract of `InputStream` requires - it will be absolutely fine.

Note that you'd be in exactly the same situation with the familiar wrapping of one resource within another, e.g.

```
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(...)) {
   try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, ...)) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Or with a single try-with-resources statement:

```
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(...);
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, ...)) {
   ...
}
```

In both cases there will be two `finally` blocks, so that first `reader.close()` is called, then `input.close()` - but `reader.close()` will close `input` anyway.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I've added the single version too. Both work, but some may find the first easier to reason about to start with.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: The comma in the second form was deliberate - it's a try-with-resources acquiring *two resources*.

Comment: But it doesn't compile, I've checked it. Did you check it as well, and it worked for you? I would be surprised, honestly, because that is incongruent with the rest of Java syntax.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: No, I hadn't checked it - sorry. Rolled back now. It really does look very wrong to me with the semi-colon.

Comment: This is the logic: comma is used in a single declaration statement, involving several variables of the same type. So it would have worked here as well had you declared two `InputStream`s.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, I can see that logic - it just looks really odd having a variable number of semi-colons within the introductory part of the statement. Neither option is really satisfactory, to be honest.

Answer (score 7):

Method `close()` of [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) (and thus, of `InputStream`) is required to be idempotent:

> If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.

Therefore it's safe to close `InputStream` more than once.

However, more generic [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface does not require its `close()` method to idempotent, therefore it may be unsafe to do the same for resources other than `Closeable`:

> Note that unlike the close method of Closeable, this close method is not required to be idempotent. In other words, calling this close method more than once may have some visible side effect, unlike Closeable.close which is required to have no effect if called more than once. However, implementers of this interface are strongly encouraged to make their close methods idempotent.

Answer (score 2):

The specification does say everything it can: if `resource.close()` throws an exception, that exception will be thrown from the construct.

The specification cannot know whether any particular `close` method will throw an exception, of course. To find that out you must test your particular resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to close it in the finally-statement.

```
InputStream stream = null;
try {
  stream = new InputStream();
  yourMethod(stream);
} catch (...) {

} finally {
  try {
    stream.close()
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    // can throw IOException while closing closed stream
  }
}
```